# AWS cloud watch log stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloud, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-glue

I have a aws glue job which loads data to a redshift table . It is a generic glue job. which accepts the table name as a parameter. How can i stream the logs of the aws glue job to two different log streams based on the table name.

eg :- awsglue job which accepts the parameter "table1" should go to the log stream for "table1"
same job which accpets the parameter "table2" should go to log stream for "table2"

Comment: Thanku used this parameter in aws glue continuous-log-logGroup . There lambda with subscription filter didn’t helped much as for each log we needed a keyword relating to table to create a filter pattern

Answer (score 0):

You can setup lambda [subscription filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/SubscriptionFilters.html#LambdaFunctionExample) on the log group normally produced by the Glue. The lambda then would analyze the logs in real time and distributed to dedicated cloudwatch logs for each table.

Comment: When we use the subscription filter what would be the filter pattern to filter the table specific logs ?@marcin

Comment: @Datagirl Not sure. I would suggest making new question with specific details. You can provide examples of current Glue logs.